# Java Bitset initialization

Tags: java, initialization, bitset

I'm using the BitSet class for my program.
I need an inline declaration like:

```
BitSet bits1 = new BitSet(); //standard declaration
bits1.set(0,2);
bits1.set(4,6);
System.out.println(bits1); //110011

BitSet bits2 = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] {1,1,0,0,1,1}); //inline
System.out.println(bits2);
```

With this code I'm trying to replicate the same BitSet that is in *bits1*, in *bits2*.
The problem is the following: the print and the values are different.
The BitSet I set is 110011. The first one prints out {0, 1, 4, 5} and it is correct since this is the "nice" way to print the BitSet with indexes, the second one prints out{0, 64, 256, 320}.
As you can see the second one is wrong. I'm pretty sure that the inline initialization is wrong, but I cannot figure out how can I fix this.

Comment: `long` has 64 bits. You need to pack the bits together if you want to use the `long[]` constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each long in the array represents 64 bits. You only need a single long with 4 bits set:

```
BitSet bits2 = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] {0b110011});
System.out.println(bits2);
// {0, 1, 4, 5}
```

Comment: That's worked for me! Just one more question: what's the meaning of 0b before 110011? Is it a kind of a constant?

Comment: @user840718 It tells the compiler to read the number as a [binary literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html).

Comment: Is there also a built-in method that prints out a BitSet in binary literal?

Comment: @user840718 Good question. I don't know of any built-in way, but here's a somewhat hacky solution: `Arrays.stream(bits2.toLongArray()).mapToObj(l -> String.format("%64s", Long.toBinaryString(l)).replace(' ', '0')).collect(Collectors.joining())`

Comment: @shmosel Shouldn't you add a `.replaceFirst("^0+(.)", "$1")` to the end of that, to remove leading zeroes? The `(.)` and `$1` are for retaining at least one digit if all zeroes.

Comment: @Andreas They're both valid representations. I went with the simpler one.

Comment: I've also found the optimized implementation called SparseBit https://github.com/brettwooldridge/SparseBitSet.
Seems to be not possible initialize here inline values, since the method valueOf is has not been implemented. Is that right?